# Python/Pandas data alignment when using plot()

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am using pandas to plot some data from a larger data set. I have the following code that sorts out specific columns (categories/description) and plots them from one large DF.

```
df.amt[df.categ=='A'].cumsum().plot(legend=True,label='A',figsize=(11,5))
df.amt[df.descrip=='B'].cumsum().plot(legend=True,label='B',figsize=(11,5))
```

When plotted the image is such:

[image]
The blue line starts at (2015, 8) and the red line starts at (2014,9) but in the plot this is not the case.

This is surely because two plot commands follow each other. How can I make the successive plot commands play nice?

Comment: Surely there is more to the plot than those two lines. Please post all relevant code with sample data for [MInimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, you've introduced data into

```
df.amt[df.descrip=='B'].cumsum().plot(legend=True,label='B',figsize=(11,5))
```

prior to when you believe.  The only way for us to really help is for you to take the time to provide more detail and more code.

consider the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(18).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])

df.loc[range(3), 'B'] = np.nan

df.A.plot(label='A')
df.B.plot(label='B')
```

[image]

```
df.A.cumsum().plot(label='A')
df.B.cumsum().plot(label='B')
```

[image]